# Auto move emails to Trash in single click?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I get bunch of nonsense emails from staffing companies or vendors daily bases.

Is there any easy if I select email move to trash and next on wards from that email address automatically can go to trash. I don't want create rules for each email. Please help me out.

Any plugin or solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question. That being said, right click on the message, select Junk | Block Sender.